# Step by step 3D Game Design in Unity

Tags: unity, 3d, game-design, blender

My main question is related to 3D game design for Unity, but please let me introduce my idea so that you can understand what I really mean.

I am very eager to develop an adventurous - travel 3D game (Unity), where the main character is given some kind of task in country A and if he deals with it, he goes to the upper level, which is in another country and so on.

I have never developed a computer game before. I have knowledge of c# and a bit of java (for the programming part of the game). But I really don`t know where to start with the design. I have to think of a main character, episodic characters, environment and distinctive buildings for each country in 3D (for e.g. The Eiffel Tower in Paris, The Colloseum in Rome, The Great wall of China etc. ).

My question is: where to begin with the 3D design of the characters, the cities and the buildings? Can you please give me step-by-step instructions so that I can do something good and meaningful?

I know that Blender is a good option for 3D modeling, but is it the only thing needed for the 3D game design? I have experience with Adobe Illustrator, so can I use it to some extent in this case (for 3D game elements)?

Can I use Illustrator then import it in Blender and finally import the Blender product in Unity?

I accept every advice given. I really need someone to explain these things to me because for now I am really puzzled and not orientated from where to begin.
Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for help with 3D modelling, not game design. 3D modelling is the process of building the meshes used to render the characters/environments/vehicles/props/etc, while "game design" is the planning of the game's rules, systems, mechanics, progression, etc. Searching for 3D modelling tutorials may get you better results.

Comment: 1. First of all you should need to learn Unity. Take any course online and learn it. Spend some time with and check that how to use unity and how to write C# script to interact with any gameobject in unity. make some cubes apply texture learn about materails assets, gameobect hirachy inspector etc.

Comment: 2. Then Learn Blender/Maya/Max for modeling your games. (I think you are a programmer you should not need to learn either you higher a modeler who can models things for you or you can visit asset store to get free/paid models for your games). Remember Unity is not a modeling tool altough very simple object you can make there